# Кеширует ли .NET коллекцию?

Tags: c#, .net

Например, есть метод, который на вход принимает массив значений.

Этот метод всегда вызывается с одними и теми же значениями и в одном месте программы и поэтому я не парясь делаю так:

```
SomeMethod(new[] {1,2,3,4})
```

Вопрос в том:

Додумается компилятор или среда где-то закешировать это или каждый раз будет создавать новый массив и в этом случае массив лучше хранить в поле класса?

Comment: Кто даст компилятору гарантии, что `SomeMethod` не изменяет переданный массив?

Comment: была бы жто строка, было бы все понятно, страка не меняется, её можно закешировать. Но это массив, массив может меняться, потому его компилятор не кеширует.

Comment: Да, лучше хранить в константе класса.

Comment: @PetSerAl Ну если тип массив содержит в себе элементы типа  ValueType, то можно легко проследить делает ли метод изменения=> если изменений нет и массив создается "на лету", то я не вижу проблем в определении возможности безопасного кеширования.

Comment: `то можно легко проследить делает ли метод изменения` wat? `Object myarr = yourArray; .. где то в другом методе.... ((int[]) myArr)[0]=123;` - удачи это проследить на стадии компиляции :)

Comment: если у вас метод принимает 4 числа всегда, и они не менябтся никогда, может имеет смысл убрать массив и сделать 4 параметра? Или убрать параметры и сделать гдето 4 константы?

Answer (score 0):

Код

```
static void Main() {
   SomeMethod(new[] {1,2,3,4});

   }
```

Преобразуется в

```
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.4
  IL_0002:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0007:  dup
  IL_0008:  ldtoken    field valuetype nnn
  IL_000d:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::InitializeArray(class [mscorlib]System.Array,
                                                                                                      valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeFieldHandle)
  IL_0012:  call       void Demo::SomeMethod(int32[])
```

newarr  - резервирует память,  а с токена посредством InitializeArray загружаются (копируются) данные об 1,2,3.

Да, лучше хранить в константе класса.

Answer (score 0):

Для строк работает [интернирование](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). Такой трюк имеет смысл потому, что они иммутабельны, чем не могут похвастать массивы, поэтому для них кэширование нужно делать руками.

> массив лучше хранить в поле класса?

В статическом поле.

```
private static readonly int[] myValues = new {1, 2, 3};

// .NET Core
private static readonly ImmutableArray<int> myValues = ImmutableArray.Create(1, 2, 3);
```